# How we can break the value, Getting ERROR - must be str, not list

Tags: python, airflow

I am new in python, Here I want to break the value on the basis of comma. I tried with split method but It's not working.

Please refer below code

```
report_name = task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='task_1', key='report_key')
print('type report name : ',type(report_name))
##INFO - type report name :  <class 'str'>
print('report name in email op : ',report_name)        
##INFO - report name in email op :  
print('str report name : ',str(report_name))    
##INFO - str report name :  report_1,report_2,report_3
t_email_success = email_operator.EmailOperator(
                task_id='t_email_success',
                to=str(user_email),
                cc='abc@sample.com'
                subject='This is sample of subject',
                html_content="""Hello,<br><br>

                                Report is generated successfully <br><br>
                                File Names : """ + str(report_name).split(",") + """<br><br>



                                Thanks & Regards,<br><br>
                                """
            )
t_email_success.execute(context=kwargs)
```

In this code I am using email operator of airflow, I am sending one email & I want report name in next line. I tried out but getting error.

My expected output is :

```
Hello,

Report is generated successfully 

File Names : report_1
report_2
report_3

Thanks & Regards
```

Any suggestion would be appreciate.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post what `str(report_name)` looks like, and your expected output ?

Comment: `report_name.split(",")` will split `report_name` on commas all right. The problem is you're trying to add the resulting list to a string. You can't add a list to a string. What exactly do you want to have after `Files: ` in the body of your mail?

Comment: Hello @SimonR,  Please check expected output and print statement of report_name

Comment: Hello @Blotosmetek, please check expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answer is OK, but I'd do it slightly differently:

```
report_name = task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='task_1', key='report_key')
print('report name in email op : ',report_name)        
template="""Hello,<br><br>
Report is generated successfully <br><br>
File Names : {}<br><br>
Thanks & Regards,<br><br>
"""
t_email_success = email_operator.EmailOperator(
                task_id='t_email_success',
                to=user_email,
                cc='abc@sample.com',
                subject='This is sample of subject',
                html_content=template.format('<br>'.join(report_name.split(',')))
            )
t_email_success.execute(context=kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a list of file names, you can just use `report_name` like you do in the forth line of your code.

`report_name` is a string, splitting it will convert it to a list. What are you trying to achieve?

If you want to have new lines after each file name you can do:

```
        html_content="""Hello,<br><br>

                        Report is generated successfully <br><br>
                        File Names : """ + report_name.replace(",","<br>") + """<br><br>



                        Thanks & Regards,<br><br>
                        """
```

But the additional file names could be not indented properly, maybe better to add a `<br>` also after the `:` :)